# google maps silverlight

Tags: silverlight, google-maps-api-3

I am working on silverlight 4 application and need to implement google maps in the same app.

Now to implement the google maps, i was planning to use WebBrowser control but when i used it i found out that it will run only in out of browser mode.

So, i decided to use another approach since i want to implement google maps inside of my application. I then used http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/09/hosting-html-in-silverlight-not-out-of.html alternative which was having to use iframe to show web page there. It was seems to be good alternative in start. But Here comes another twist.

On top of my app, i have one top MENU for navigation, its a classic web menu, user hover over the menu item and its sub item will expand vertically.

Now just underneath the MENU i have above HTML control to display my map. Now since the HTML browser control has higher z-Index so my vertical sub menu is goes underneath the google map and hence it not visible.
And giving silverlight app higher z-Index the iframe for HTML does not show up as it goes behind the app.

So how can i get my HTML MAP and MENU both to work? If you guys have any other alternative to implement google maps then please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Silverlight Bing Maps control, with the tile-source set to Google Maps. This will give you the maps you desire, via a proper Silverlight control. You can find out about how to provide a custom tile source from Google here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/02/google-sky-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: It is, however there are numerous applications on the windows phone marketplace that do just this.

Comment: Im saying it just because I don't have an answer to OP. In a same boat and using Bing maps with control. It may fly with some apps but in case of business app it's a NO-NO. In addition, control need to verify credentials against  Bing account even if you use Google tiles. Just a precaution.

Comment: I am having an business app so dont want any legal issue here. Will try to change the drop down menus to something else.